# How to judge if there are merged cells in a table in a word document using vsto?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, vsto

Is there a way to tell if there are merged cells in a table in a word document?

When I traveled through the word document in accordance with the tables and change table and cell properties, my program error, because some table contains merged cells, but if I according to the cell to traverse, due to the document content may be a lot of, this will take a long time, I know there is an attribute MergeCells in excel, but word if do not have this property...

```cs
 Range FR = wordDoc.Range(sRange.Start, sRange.End);
  for (int i = 1; i <= FR.Tables.Count; i++)
                    {
                        //Range IsMerge = FR.Tables[i].Range;
                        //if (IsMerge)
                        //{

                        //}


                        for (int j = 1; j <= FR.Tables[i].Rows.Count; j++)
                        {
                            Range rg = FR.Tables[i].Rows[j].Range;

                            object Replace_String = "^p";       
                            object ms = Type.Missing;
                            object Replace = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;
                            object ReplaceWith = "";            
                            rg.Find.Execute(ref Replace_String, ref ms, ref ms, ref ms, ref ms,
                                ref ms, ref ms, ref ms, ref ms, ref ReplaceWith,
                                ref Replace, ref ms, ref ms, ref ms, ref ms);

                            rg.ParagraphFormat.FirstLineIndent = 0;
                            rg.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;
                        }
                    }
```

Individual rows in this collection cannot be accessed because the table has vertically merged cells.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to check Word tables in VBA for vertically or horizontally merged cells. You have to anticipate the specific returned error code and then react accordingly. You can convert it to C#.

```
Sub WorkWithTableData()
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim i As Long, tblRow As Row, tblCol As Column
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    On Error GoTo errHandler
    For i = 1 To doc.Tables.Count
        For Each tblRow In doc.Tables(i).rows
            'do something
        Next tblRow
NextStep:
        For Each tblCol In doc.Tables(i).Columns
            'do something
        Next tblCol
NextTable:
    Next i
    Exit Sub
errHandler:
    Select Case Err
        Case 5991
            MsgBox "Table #" & i & " has vertically merged cells"
            Resume NextStep
        Case 5992
            MsgBox "Table #" & i & " has horizontally merged cells"
            Resume NextTable
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & _
                Err.Description & " in table #" & i
            Resume NextTable
    End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to check whether a table has merged cells you can use the `Uniform` property:

```
if (FR.Tables[i].Uniform)
{
  //Do actions for the case the table has no merged cells
}
```